# Blow up commute with base change

Tags: algebraic-geometry, blowup

Let $X$ be an irreducible Noetherian scheme and $X_{red}$ be the reduced subscheme associated to it. This induces a natural morphism from $X_{red}$ to $X$. Fix a point $p$ in $X$ (by a point we mean an irreducible zero dimensional closed subscheme of $X$, so can be non-reduced). Denote by $Bl_pX$ the blow up of $X$ along $p$ in the sense stated in Chapter II.$7$ of "Algebraic Geometry" by Hartshorne. Is it true that the pull-back $Bl_pX \times_X X_{red}$ is the blow up of $X_{red}$ at $p_{red}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer I think is yes.

Denote by $\pi_1$ the natural projection map from $Bl_pX \times_X X_{red}$ to $X_{red}$.
Using Proposition IV-$21$ in "Geometry of Schemes" by Eisenbud and Harris, we conclude that the blow up of $X_{red}$ at $p_{red}$ is the closure of $\pi_1^{-1}(X_{red}\backslash p_{red})$ in $Bl_pX \times_X X_{red}$. Note further that $X\backslash p$ is dense in $Bl_p X$. Since the image of $X_{red}\backslash p_{red}$ is dense in $X$, it should follow that the closure of $\pi^{-1}(X_{red}\backslash p_{red})$ is $Bl_pX \times_X X_{red}$.

**EDIT** As pointed out below, the argument is true if $p_{red}=p \times_{X} X_{red}$.

Comment: Dear @Jana, I would like to see some more explanations. In particular, which structure of subscheme do you endow $\pi^{-1}(X_{red}\setminus p_{red})$ with ?

Comment: @Cantlog: Take any closed point $x \in X$. By definition there exists a closed point $x_{red} \in X_{red}$ in the preimage of $x$. If $x$ is not $p$ then we simply take the tensor product of the stalks of the structure sheaves. If $x=p$, we can choose a point on the fiber of $x$ and then take the tensor product of the stalks of the structure sheaves at the corresponding points. Please feel free to point out any mistake.

Comment: Dear @Jana, I just checked in Eisenbud and Harris, they say that the closure in question is the blow-up of $X_{red}$ at $X_{red}\times_X p$. But the later is not $p_{red}$ in general (e.g. when $X$ itself is reduced but not $p$).

Comment: @Cantlog: I understand. Thanks. I was assuming that $p_{red}$ is infact the fiber product that you mentioned. I am editing my answer.

Comment: Then I agree. In the original message, $p_{red}$ is not defined, but by analogy with $X_{red}$, it should be the reduced scheme associated to $p$.